# Valgrind error - can not open cache simulation output file

Tags: valgrind

I try to profile my program with **Valgrind**:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=/home/user/callgrind.%p --instr-atstart=no ./src/Leonardo --https leosd:11443
```

After I reach my file where in my target-profile function I have:

```
CALLGRIND_START_INSTRUMENTATION;

/* a lot of code to profile */

CALLGRIND_STOP_INSTRUMENTATION;
CALLGRIND_DUMP_STATS;
```

The program crashes and the output in the console is:

> ==3117== Error: can not open cache simulation output file `/home/user/callgrind.3117.1014'

P.S. If I run the `valgrind` from QtCreator with profiling from application start it runs perfectly but I dont need this.

Any idea how to fix this? Google does not help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had de same problem and I solved going to project and in the run section remove tick from "run in terminal"

Answer (score -1):

Try first more basic things i.e.

1. do not give the option --callgrind-out-file
2. do not give the option --instr-at-start=no
3. do not insert CALLGRIND_START/STOP_INSTRUMENTATION

So, in other words, just do:
    valgrind --tool=callgrind your_program your_program_args

Then when the simple basic usage works, try adding one thing at a time.

Typically, the 'can not open cache simulation' is because the directory
does not exist or is not writable or a similar problem.
If the basic usage does not work, file a bug on Valgrind bugzilla, giving
the relevant information (platform/version/...)